# In this derivation of the transverse wave equation, why is the force multiplied by the change in $x$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, waves, free-body-diagram

I'm reading this derivation of the transverse wave equation, and I follow everything except for point (c) on  [the outline](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m256/wave.pdf). Why is a force multiplied by the change in $x$. Isn't this Work--not Force? It doesn't make a lot of sense in this context.

Comment: I disagree that this is unclear; however, my issue has been answered, and I upvoted it. There's no need to put this on hold. It can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context $F(x,t)$ does *not* mean force, rather it is the external applied force per unit length. So that

$$
F(x,t)\Delta x
$$

means the actual force acting on the element of length $\Delta x$

Answer (score 0):

In this case $\Delta x$ is not representing a change, but just the length of the element that is under consideration.

The gravitational force depends on the mass, so the force is proportional to the mass, or in this case proportional to the horizontal length.  Larger element, larger force.